# How to use f# constraints for generic calculation functions?

Tags: f#, inline, type-constraints

```
type Point<'t> =
    val X : 't
    val Y : 't
    new(x : 't,y : 't) = { X = x; Y = y }

let clampedSubtract (p1:Point<_>) (p2:Point<_>) =
    Point( max (p2.X - p1.X) 0, max (p2.Y - p1.Y) 0 )
```

If you look at the code above, you will notice, that the function is not implemented as generic as it should be.

First, using the 0 in the max expressions clamps the type to int. But it should be the type of whatever type `Point<'t>` has and not `Point<int>`.

But even more important, this function can only work as expected, if signed types are used for `t.

This raises a few questions of mine:

1. Is there a way to obtain the neutral element (zero) from a generic (number) type?
2. How can I express a restriction such as "only signed number"?
3. Is there a way to extend type constraint system in F#?

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: There is a way to create your custom numeric type in F# as described here: http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-custom-numeric.aspx/index.html  In this case you can put your set of constraints on it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution to the first question as already answered is to use an inline function together with GenericZero and that's all.

Regarding the signed restriction, actually there's an easy way to restrict it to signed types. Use somewhere the generic unary negation which is defined only for signed types:

```
let inline clampedSubtract (p1:Point<_>) (p2:Point<_>) =
    let zero = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
    Point( max (p2.X + -p1.X) zero, max (p2.Y + -p1.Y) zero )

let result1 = clampedSubtract (Point(4  , 5  )) (Point(4  , 5  ))
let result2 = clampedSubtract (Point(4y , 5y )) (Point(4y , 5y ))
let result3 = clampedSubtract (Point(4uy, 5uy)) (Point(4uy, 5uy)) // doesn't compile
```

In general, if you want to restrict any generic function to signed types you can define this function:

```
let inline whenSigned x = ignore (-x)

let inline clampedSubtract (p1:Point<_>) (p2:Point<_>) =
    whenSigned p1.X
    let zero = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
    Point( max (p2.X - p1.X) zero, max (p2.Y - p1.Y) zero )
```

Finally regarding your third question it's not very clear to me what do you mean with extending the type system. You can create static constraints by yourself, in that sense the system is already extensible.

I did a project sometime ago to emulate some Haskell types, part of the code of that project is still in a module in [FsControl](https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl/blob/master/FsControl.Core/Numeric.fs) there you can have an idea to what level you can play with those constraints.

Comment: This function that introduces the additional constraint gets actually executed. Granted, no big deal here. But if you were naming the type variable, a mere function definition like `let dummy (p : Point<'T>) = -p.X` would carry the constraint instead, without ever calling the `(~-)` operator.

Comment: Good point, if you're caring about performance as well  every single cycle counts.

Answer (score 5):

This makes it generic:

```
let inline clampedSubtract (p1:Point<_>) (p2:Point<_>) =
    let zero = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
    Point( max (p2.X - p1.X) zero, max (p2.Y - p1.Y) zero )
```

But there's no way to constrain it to signed primitive types.

Comment: Nice - now the 0 problem is fixed :) Before I tick the answer as accepted, I will wait a bit to see if someone else has ideas for the other parts of the question.

Comment: @user2225104 The way Stack Overflow works, you have more chances of getting all your questions answered if you ask each question as a separate post/article.